# Snowflake create table syntax

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm developing a program to parse sql queries I'm getting.
I've encountered a syntax I'm not familiar with:

```
create table if not exists identifier(table1) ("ID" INTEGER)
```

I'm not familiar with the identifier usage and couldn't find any relevant documentation.
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid SQL statement? Snowflake has an article on "identifier" requirements: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers.html, but it doesn't seem like the syntax above actually works when I try to run it.

Comment: What is the syntax error you are getting?

Comment: And how are you setting the value for `table1`

Comment: this is not a query I'm executing. This is a query i'm getting while testing the query history (the actual queries are executed by the user). 

I wasn't able to execute it on my local snowflake, but seen it a few times so I do guess it's a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell whether you are trying to use an identifier() function to use a variable or not, but if you are, I think you're looking for something like this:

```
set table1 = 'my_table';

create table if not exists identifier($table1)(ID integer);
```

As an additional note, I wouldn't use double-quotes around your column names unless you are trying to escape a special character.

If you are not trying to use a variable in your table name, then just get rid of the identifier() function altogether.

Comment: Hi @Mike, thank you for the help. I don't have the full context but not sure it's a variable as all of those queries didn't include the $ sign.